# How to resolve an outer async function from an inner function

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-next

How do i resolve the outer async function askIfUserIsAMinor with a boolean indicating the user's minor status (true/false) after the user has answered a dialog prompt? For example:

```
async function askIfUserIsAMinor() {
  let dialogButtons = [
    {
      text: "Yes",
      onPress: () => {
        // I want to return 'false' on the outer async function 
      }
    }, 
    {
      text: "No",
      onPress: () => {
        // I want to return 'true' on the outer async function 
      }
    }
  ];
  dialog.prompt("Are you above the age of 18?", dialogButtons);
}

let userIsAMinor = await askIfUserIsAMinor();
if (userIsAMinor) {
  // let user proceed
} else {
  // show something else
}
```

Yes, there are many other ways to solve this problem without async/await, but my use case is much more complex than this, this is just a simplified scenario. In ES6, this can be solved by having `askIfUserIsAMinor` return a promise and having the inner `onPress` functions call `resolve` on the outer promise.

Comment: you're using `await` incorrectly ... I would've expected to see `return await dialog.prompt(...` - though, not knowing what dialog or dialog.prompt code even looks like, it's hard to say

Comment: I've expanded the comment

Comment: Lets say dialog is like a library method that shows the prompt, and calls the attached functions to each button when pressed. We can't modify dialog.prompt to an `await`-able `async function`.

Comment: how is dialog.prompt used in general? does it return a promise for example, or is there a callback parameter? in other words, take away async/await - how does dialog.prompt work?

Comment: Entirely callback based, it does not return a promise, the callbacks to each button are attached to `onPress`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code actually works correctly - promisify the dialog.prompt, then you await on the promise in the `async function testMinor` - the code I posted earlier fell for the same trap other people always fall for, thinking somehow one can make asynch code synchronous ...

```
function askIfUserIsAMinor() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        let dialogButtons = [{
            text: "Yes",
            onPress: () => resolve(true)
        }, {
            text: "No",
            onPress: () => resolve(false)
        }];
        dialog.prompt("Are you above the age of 18?", dialogButtons);
    });
}
async function testMinor() {
    let userIsAMinor = await askIfUserIsAMinor();
    if (userIsAMinor) {
      // let user proceed
    } else {
      // show something else
    }
}
```

---

or

```
async function askIfUserIsAMinor() {
    let userIsAMinor = await new Promise(function(resolve) {
        let dialogButtons = [{
            text: "Yes",
            onPress: () => resolve(true)
        }, {
            text: "No",
            onPress: () => resolve(false)
        }];
        dialog.prompt("Are you above the age of 18?", dialogButtons);
    });
    if (userIsAMinor) {
      // let user proceed
    } else {
      // show something else
    }
}
askIfUserIsAMinor();
```

Comment: Does it work? To be honest I guessed based on my limited reading of ES2016/ES7 - still catching up with ES2015/ES6

Comment: In theory it should. Testing it out now. Just kinda annoyed that ES7 async/await is supposed to be used as an improvement over ES6 promises, but we have to fallback to promises whenever more complex scenarios such as these show up.

Comment: @GeoffreyGoh - edited the answer - the above should work but maybe not quite as you want